# Removing matching elements in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON object. I would like to go through it and if the element has a matching co-ordinate, delete the copy and retain the original. I've tried using .filter to strip away the copies but i'm unable to get it working. What would be the best way to strip away copies?

```
business1 {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    12.564111,
                    55.675659
                ]
            },
            "place_name": "Axeltorv 3, 1609 København, Denmark",
            "properties": {
                "title": "Comparison of Alternative Meat Inspection Regimes for Pigs From Non-Controlled Housing ? Considering the Cost of Error",
                "countries": "Denmark",
                "authorTitle": "Lis Alban",
                "businessName": "Danish Agriculture and Food Council"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    12.564111,
                    55.675659
                ]
            },
            "place_name": "Axeltorv 3, 1609 København, Denmark",
            "properties": {
                "title": "Comparison of Alternative Meat Inspection Regimes for Pigs From Non-Controlled Housing ? Considering the Cost of Error",
                "countries": "Denmark",
                "authorTitle": "Lisbeth Harm Nielsen",
                "businessName": "Danish Agriculture and Food Council"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -1.26288597488275,
                    51.7576388596821
                ]
            },
            "place_name": "OX1 2JD, Oxford, Oxfordshire, England, United Kingdom",
            "properties": {
                "title": "ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics",
                "countries": "United Kingdom",
                "authorTitle": "C?cile A J Girardin",
                "businessName": "University of Oxford"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -1.26288597488275,
                    51.7576388596821
                ]
            },
            "place_name": "OX1 2JD, Oxford, Oxfordshire, England, United Kingdom",
            "properties": {
                "title": "ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics",
                "countries": "United Kingdom",
                "authorTitle": "Cecilia A L Dahlsj?",
                "businessName": "University of Oxford"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -111.65511,
                    35.19363
                ]
            },
            "place_name": "1899 PO Box, Flagstaff, Arizona 86011, United States",
            "properties": {
                "title": "ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics",
                "countries": "United States",
                "authorTitle": "Christopher E Doughty",
                "businessName": "Northern Arizona University"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -1.26288597488275,
                    51.7576388596821
                ]
            },
            "place_name": "OX1 2JD, Oxford, Oxfordshire, England, United Kingdom",
            "properties": {
                "title": "ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics",
                "countries": "United Kingdom",
                "authorTitle": "Erika Berenguer",
                "businessName": "University of Oxford"
            }
        }
    ],

}
```

Would become the following with just the original rather than a mix of copies.

```
business1 {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    12.564111,
                    55.675659
                ]
            },
            "place_name": "Axeltorv 3, 1609 København, Denmark",
            "properties": {
                "title": "Comparison of Alternative Meat Inspection Regimes for Pigs From Non-Controlled Housing ? Considering the Cost of Error",
                "countries": "Denmark",
                "authorTitle": "Lis Alban",
                "businessName": "Danish Agriculture and Food Council"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -1.26288597488275,
                    51.7576388596821
                ]
            },
            "place_name": "OX1 2JD, Oxford, Oxfordshire, England, United Kingdom",
            "properties": {
                "title": "ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics",
                "countries": "United Kingdom",
                "authorTitle": "Cecilia A L Dahlsj?",
                "businessName": "University of Oxford"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -111.65511,
                    35.19363
                ]
            },
            "place_name": "1899 PO Box, Flagstaff, Arizona 86011, United States",
            "properties": {
                "title": "ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics",
                "countries": "United States",
                "authorTitle": "Christopher E Doughty",
                "businessName": "Northern Arizona University"
            }
        }
    ],

}
```

Attempt using set, it just returns the exact object passed to it

```
 uniqueArray = [...new Set(business1.features)]
```

Comment: Please show your attempt to do this using `.filter()`.

Comment: what criteria would you use to determine a match? just the coordinates, or the place name, or exact match for the whole object?

Comment: whatever is easiest, the coordinates will give the same place name so I was thinking just the coordinates. Will update OP with my attempts

Comment: `whatever is easiest` - it's not about ease it's about accuracy :p

Comment: An element with the same coordinates might have a different author. It's just how the object is made up after items are sent to a geocoder... So I'm only looking to find a way to get rid of an element if a matching coordinates exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

You can do this with `Array.prototype.filter` by destructuring down to coordinates and checking a locally scoped `Set` for the stringified array.

---

### Code:

```
business1.features.filter(({geometry:{ coordinates }}) => 
  !b.has(s(coordinates)) && (b.add(s(coordinates)), true), 
  b = new Set(), s = JSON.stringify)
```

### Commented Code:

```
  // Get the features array
  business1.features

  // call filter on the array
  .filter(

  // destructure each feature down to "coordinates"
  ({geometry:{ coordinates }}) => 

  /* check if the local set object contains stringified coordinates
  if it does not - 
   - we add it to the set and respond true
   - it is added to the filtered array
  if it does - 
    - we respond false
    - it is not added to the filtered array.
  */
  !b.has(s(coordinates)) && (b.add(s(coordinates)), true), 

  // declare our local variables for our Set and stringify:
  b = new Set(), s = JSON.stringify)
```

---

### Working Code:

```js
let business1={type:"FeatureCollection",features:[{type:"Feature",geometry:{type:"Point",coordinates:[12.564111,55.675659]},place_name:"Axeltorv 3, 1609 København, Denmark",properties:{title:"Comparison of Alternative Meat Inspection Regimes for Pigs From Non-Controlled Housing ? Considering the Cost of Error",countries:"Denmark",authorTitle:"Lis Alban",businessName:"Danish Agriculture and Food Council"}},{type:"Feature",geometry:{type:"Point",coordinates:[12.564111,55.675659]},place_name:"Axeltorv 3, 1609 København, Denmark",properties:{title:"Comparison of Alternative Meat Inspection Regimes for Pigs From Non-Controlled Housing ? Considering the Cost of Error",countries:"Denmark",authorTitle:"Lisbeth Harm Nielsen",businessName:"Danish Agriculture and Food Council"}},{type:"Feature",geometry:{type:"Point",coordinates:[-1.26288597488275,51.7576388596821]},place_name:"OX1 2JD, Oxford, Oxfordshire, England, United Kingdom",properties:{title:"ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics",countries:"United Kingdom",authorTitle:"C?cile A J Girardin",businessName:"University of Oxford"}},{type:"Feature",geometry:{type:"Point",coordinates:[-1.26288597488275,51.7576388596821]},place_name:"OX1 2JD, Oxford, Oxfordshire, England, United Kingdom",properties:{title:"ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics",countries:"United Kingdom",authorTitle:"Cecilia A L Dahlsj?",businessName:"University of Oxford"}},{type:"Feature",geometry:{type:"Point",coordinates:[-111.65511,35.19363]},place_name:"1899 PO Box, Flagstaff, Arizona 86011, United States",properties:{title:"ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics",countries:"United States",authorTitle:"Christopher E Doughty",businessName:"Northern Arizona University"}},{type:"Feature",geometry:{type:"Point",coordinates:[-1.26288597488275,51.7576388596821]},place_name:"OX1 2JD, Oxford, Oxfordshire, England, United Kingdom",properties:{title:"ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics",countries:"United Kingdom",authorTitle:"Erika Berenguer",businessName:"University of Oxford"}}]};



let result = business1.features.filter(({geometry:{ coordinates }}) => 
  !b.has(s(coordinates)) && (b.add(s(coordinates)), true), b = new Set(), s = JSON.stringify)

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) to make your life easier. In particular the [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqBy) function of lodash. I have deduplicated based on matching coordinates. Full working example below:

```js
const featureCollection = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          12.564111,
          55.675659
        ]
      },
      "place_name": "Axeltorv 3, 1609 København, Denmark",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Comparison of Alternative Meat Inspection Regimes for Pigs From Non-Controlled Housing ? Considering the Cost of Error",
        "countries": "Denmark",
        "authorTitle": "Lis Alban",
        "businessName": "Danish Agriculture and Food Council"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          12.564111,
          55.675659
        ]
      },
      "place_name": "Axeltorv 3, 1609 København, Denmark",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Comparison of Alternative Meat Inspection Regimes for Pigs From Non-Controlled Housing ? Considering the Cost of Error",
        "countries": "Denmark",
        "authorTitle": "Lisbeth Harm Nielsen",
        "businessName": "Danish Agriculture and Food Council"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-1.26288597488275,
          51.7576388596821
        ]
      },
      "place_name": "OX1 2JD, Oxford, Oxfordshire, England, United Kingdom",
      "properties": {
        "title": "ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics",
        "countries": "United Kingdom",
        "authorTitle": "C?cile A J Girardin",
        "businessName": "University of Oxford"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-1.26288597488275,
          51.7576388596821
        ]
      },
      "place_name": "OX1 2JD, Oxford, Oxfordshire, England, United Kingdom",
      "properties": {
        "title": "ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics",
        "countries": "United Kingdom",
        "authorTitle": "Cecilia A L Dahlsj?",
        "businessName": "University of Oxford"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-111.65511,
          35.19363
        ]
      },
      "place_name": "1899 PO Box, Flagstaff, Arizona 86011, United States",
      "properties": {
        "title": "ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics",
        "countries": "United States",
        "authorTitle": "Christopher E Doughty",
        "businessName": "Northern Arizona University"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-1.26288597488275,
          51.7576388596821
        ]
      },
      "place_name": "OX1 2JD, Oxford, Oxfordshire, England, United Kingdom",
      "properties": {
        "title": "ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics",
        "countries": "United Kingdom",
        "authorTitle": "Erika Berenguer",
        "businessName": "University of Oxford"
      }
    }
  ],
};

featureCollection.features = _.uniqBy(featureCollection.features, (b) => b.geometry.coordinates[0] && b.geometry.coordinates[1]);
console.log(featureCollection);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple filter using findIndex should be enough

```js
const business1 = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[12.564111,55.675659]},"place_name":"Axeltorv 3, 1609 København, Denmark","properties":{"title":"Comparison of Alternative Meat Inspection Regimes for Pigs From Non-Controlled Housing ? Considering the Cost of Error","countries":"Denmark","authorTitle":"Lis Alban","businessName":"Danish Agriculture and Food Council"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[12.564111,55.675659]},"place_name":"Axeltorv 3, 1609 København, Denmark","properties":{"title":"Comparison of Alternative Meat Inspection Regimes for Pigs From Non-Controlled Housing ? Considering the Cost of Error","countries":"Denmark","authorTitle":"Lisbeth Harm Nielsen","businessName":"Danish Agriculture and Food Council"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-1.26288597488275,51.7576388596821]},"place_name":"OX1 2JD, Oxford, Oxfordshire, England, United Kingdom","properties":{"title":"ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics","countries":"United Kingdom","authorTitle":"C?cile A J Girardin","businessName":"University of Oxford"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-1.26288597488275,51.7576388596821]},"place_name":"OX1 2JD, Oxford, Oxfordshire, England, United Kingdom","properties":{"title":"ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics","countries":"United Kingdom","authorTitle":"Cecilia A L Dahlsj?","businessName":"University of Oxford"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-111.65511,35.19363]},"place_name":"1899 PO Box, Flagstaff, Arizona 86011, United States","properties":{"title":"ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics","countries":"United States","authorTitle":"Christopher E Doughty","businessName":"Northern Arizona University"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-1.26288597488275,51.7576388596821]},"place_name":"OX1 2JD, Oxford, Oxfordshire, England, United Kingdom","properties":{"title":"ENSO Drives interannual variation of forest woody growth across the tropics","countries":"United Kingdom","authorTitle":"Erika Berenguer","businessName":"University of Oxford"}}]};

business1.features = business1.features.filter(
    ({geometry:{coordinates:[lat,lon]}}, index, array) => 
        array.findIndex(({geometry:{coordinates:[slat,slon]}}) => 
            lat === slat && lon === slon) === index
);


console.log(business1)
```